# Is resignFirstResponder needed in iOS7 to hide keyboard?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

Use to, this type of syntax was needed in the "Did End On Exit" action of a UITextField:

```
[self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

At least in the simulator of Xcocde 5, that code seems to be no longer needed.  The keyboard will hide when you press the return button and there is no associated action attached.  Is that correct or is this simulator only behavior?

I guess this code is still needed for iOS6?

Comment: Well there are some circumstance you will want it no ?
lets say if you are using the return button for \n you don't want the keyboard to disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the premise of your question is wrong. Nothing has changed, except that you've discovered the truth. It was *never* necessary to say `resignFirstResponder` if a text field targeted its "did end on exit" action: the mere fact of the targeting caused (and still causes) the Return key to perform dismissal *automatically*.

In fact, the "did end on exit" action doesn't actually have to *do* anything; *no* corresponding method need be implemented. And the target need not be a real object; it can be nil. In other words, this code will endow any text field with the "magical" property that it *automatically dismisses the keyboard* when the Return key is pressed:

```
[textField addTarget:nil action:@selector(dummy:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

That works (and has worked since as early as I've been using iOS, i.e. iOS 3) even though the target is nil and the action method is never implemented anywhere (there is no `dummy:` method in the app). It always surprises me that this important technique is not more widely known.

Comment: Explained further in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_text_field_delegate_and_control_event_messages

Comment: Why are all the examples for hiding a keyboard some type of attached action that implements something like [textfield1 resignFirstResponder]?

Comment: In the [immortal words of Dr. Samuel Johnson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_error): "Pure ignorance". :)

Comment: Saying `resignFirstResponder` is _a_ way (in _most_ cases) to cause dismissal of the keyboard. But it is not the _only_ way. You now know another.

Comment: And there is a third way (telling the view controller's view to `endEditing:`). And of course in iOS 7 there is a fourth way (a scroll view containing a text field can let the user dismiss the keyboard automatically by scrolling). And of course on the iPad the user can _always_ dismiss the keyboard manually.

Comment: Awesome!  Nice link by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You still need it. To close a keyboard I make an action called "close keyboard" and connect that to my text field or text view. Here is the code...

```
-(IBAction)closeKeyboard {

[textfield1 resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: Why does the keyboard still hide without any action?

Comment: what do you mean. The action is above in the answer. You connect that action to a text field and when the done or return button is tapped on the keyboard, it goes away.